# How to send mouse up to div using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, mouseup

I have simple VBScript that does next actions:

1. Open browser
2. Fill inputs( login, password and etc. )

There is the button( looks like  ) for sending information on page. 
Click event for this button does not work because it is GWT button. 
I want to send to this button MouseUp event.

How can I do it using VBScript?

```
Function Main
 Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
 IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate "http://example.com"
 With IE.Document
  .getElementByID("login").value = "Login"
  .getElementByID("password").value = "Password"
  'It doesn't work
  .getElementByID("div-button").MouseUp 
 End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Could fire events using [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

```
.getElementByID("div-button").fireEvent "onmouseup"
```

Comment: No, I could not, maybe GWT works bad in IE, or maybe in IE 9 fireEvent does not work

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using

```
Function Main
 ' ...
 Dim objShell
 Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
 objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
 objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Function
```